# How to verify if an account activation email was sent or not in Ruby on Rails web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was building a web app with account activation feature. I am following Michael Hartl ROR tutorial and I am not getting any account activation email to my inbox. I tried to search online on how to verify if at all an email was sent. Like there should be an SMTP server we configure to send emails right? Did not find anything helpful. Can someone help pls?

My account_activations_controller.rb

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

User_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end
end
```

application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  host = 'localhost:3000'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host=> host }
```

Comment: u need activate account or configure sending email?

Comment: You should add some details about how you are trying to send the email, rather than assuming everyone is familiar with a tutorial.  Any email-sending method will require you to do a bit of config to get it to work.  Have you done that?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sorry for my assumption, I have updated my question with config details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandeep,

Keep reading the tutorial.  I used an older version Michael's tutorial to learn rails,  but came back when I wanted to send confirmation emails as well.  I don't think you should expect an actual email to be sent (at least not in development mode),  rails 4.1.x has mailer previews that you can view, which I think is what the tutorial covers.

When you get to a production environment, then you will need to set up an external server to send the actual email, but that will be in your production.rb file.  If you are just learning, then you have many options, including setting up a gmail account (separate from your private account) in which to send a limited number of emails per day.

Here is the link I think you should look at:
[listing 10.15](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#code-generated_user_mailer_previews)

My experience with Michael Hartl's tutorial was that it was almost flawless,  you may have an issue or two with your particular system setup, but I think for the most part any issues I had were related to me not following the text properly.

Hope this help, good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I did not know that I should not expect email to be sent in development mode untill now. I did not see it anywhere.
Yes, I read about setting up gmail account in production.rb file for sending emails. I entered the same details in users.rb thinking it would work in my dev environment. 
Anyways I will continue with the tutorials. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I meant development.rb file not users.rb

Answer (score 1):

Reading from the bottom of page 491: "Note that you will *not* receive an actual email in a development environment, but it will show up in your server logs. Section 10.3 discusses how to send email for real in a production environment."

So if you're wanting to follow the text explicitly, I'd checkout the goodies in Section 10.3. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `config/environments/development.rb` file

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

so you get notified if there is an error on email delivery.

Other than that you can add a field to the `users` table like `activation_sent_at` and populate it when sending the email so you can refer to it later.

Comment: I have set config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors to true. How/Where do I get notified exactly please? In development.log??

Comment: I see in my log that mail has been sent. But I don't have it in my inbox,

Comment: This way it will raise an error if there was a problem in your code when delivering the mail. I highly suggest you to read through the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) .

Comment: There is a good  [gem](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) that may help you.